# Javadoc in Netbeans using Mac os x

Tags: macos, netbeans, javadoc

I have installed Netbeans on my Mac Os X and started develop using Java. The problem is that Netbeans doesn't show javadoc and i really don't know how to attach it and where to get it.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click the project Select
2. Properties Select "Java Sources
3. Classpath" Click "Manage Java
4. Platforms..." Click the platform
5. being used by the project
6. Click the Javadoc tab Click the "Add
7. ZIP/Folder..." button Select the
8. Javadoc you have downloaded to your machine

see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html)